# Can't use grub after bios update

Tags: grub2, bios

I have a Dell G3 3779 with dual-boot: Windows10 and Ubuntu18.04. After the latest bios update(1.10.0) I can't boot into Ubuntu, the Grub seems to not work after the update.

I have tried some methods but none worked:

I tried to set grub as the boot manager using cmd but it didn't work,
Using boot repair didn't fix my problem,
Reinstalling grub didn't work either,
I tried reinstalling ubuntu, but it didn't work,
I tried to downgrade the bios, but the update is blocked,

Comment: Are you still able to boot Windows from the GRUB menu? If you try and boot Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, EXACTLY what happens? After the BIOS update, did you do a "reset BIOS to standard defaults"? Are you able to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: I am able to boot Ubuntu from a usb. The problem is that the grub menu doesn't show up, it boots me directly into windows, I tried to boot ubuntu from bios and it tells me no bootable devices to be found, but the linux is there, I could access its partitions from the usb. Even after I reinstalled ubuntu 2 times it didn't work and it still boots me into windows.

Comment: In Windows, you have to reset the boot path/manager using `bcdedit` to shimx64.efi. Rather than using the command line `bcdedit`, you can install `Visual BCD Editor` found at https://www.boyans.net/. Search here on AU for "bcdedit" to see how others have done this.

Comment: UEFI update often resets UEFI settings. You may just need to turn UEFI Secure Boot off or upgrade Ubuntu to the secure boot kernel & version of grub. there may be some other settings you should check in UEFI also.

Comment: I tried the bcdedit now and the boot path was the right one, the problem is that with the new bios update microsoft/dell/intel end legacy booting mode, grub being legacy. So there is no more support for grub

Answer (score 0):

I have Dell G5 5587, and I had a problem with dual boot after BIOS update.
After some research, I could hack around it.

1. After installing both OSes.
2. I  mounted the EFI partition, using live Linux USB or from cmd using `mountvol b: /s` (`b:` is where you mount the partition)
3. I got into the EFI folder and changed the names of (**boot**, **Microsoft**, **ubuntu** - or any other disto)
4. I renamed `*boot*` to `*boot.bak*` (as a backup in case the laptop wouldn't boot.
5. I renamed `Microsoft` to `_Microsoft` (or any other name you will need it later).
6. I renamed `ubuntu` to `boot`.
7. I got into the new `boot` directory, then I changed the name of `grubx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`.
8. I added the following to my `grub.cfg` in `/boot/grub/`.

```
menuentry "Windows 10 (loader)"{
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid (type the UUID of the efi partition)
    chainloader /EFI/_Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

- Notice that `_Microsoft` is the name to which I renamed `Microsoft` folder.
- To check the UUID of the EFI partition using `sudo blkid` in Linux.

9. Now grub would work after rebooting.

   - Notice that I use **gpt** partition table.
   - To understand what is happening (not sure 100% about this):

     1. UEFI looks for `Microsoft` directory to boot into Windows (using Windows boot loader). Which is why we changed its name.
     2. If it doesn't find it, it uses `boot` directory as a fallback to boot into Windows (Windows boot manager). That is why I changed grub folder 'ubuntu' to 'boot' to make UEFI use it instead of Windows boot manager.
     3. Then I added Windows 10 boot loader manually path to grub. As grub won't find it just by using 'update-grub' or 'grub-install'.